# Summing in R on time criteria

Tags: r

I have a dataset (called stamp data) that looks like this:

```
Date_Time            Cost   
---------           -----  
01/02/2015 01:52 PM    6     
01/02/2015 02:22 PM    2    
01/03/2015 02:42 PM    50   
01/04/2015 03:01 PM    25
```

And a different data set (customer data) that looks like this:

```
Purchase_time            Amount
-------------         ---------
01/02/2015 01:57 PM         5
01/02/2015 02:46 PM         12
01/02/2015 03:13 PM         2
01/02/2015 03:30 PM         8
```

I would like to sum the "Amount" column from customer data over the Date_Time column from stamp data for different time windows, with the end result looking like this:

```
Date_Time            Cost     Amount_15min   Amount_30min
---------           -----    --------------  -------------
01/02/2015 01:52 PM    6          5             5
01/02/2015 02:22 PM    2          0            12
01/03/2015 02:42 PM    50         12           12
01/04/2015 03:01 PM    25         8            8
```

Ideally, I would like to create columns for 15 minute intervals, going through to 360 minutes (or more)

How can I do this in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find most of this code straightforward. We will need to convert the dates to POSIX objects to perform mathematical operations on them. POSIX objects are stored as integers that represent seconds passed since 01/01/1970, so when performing math on them, we will convert to numeric, then add/subtract seconds from them.

```
### Build test data frame
### times is a character vector and cost is a numeric vector
times <- c(
"01/02/2015 01:52 PM",
"01/02/2015 01:57 PM",
"01/02/2015 01:58 PM",
"01/02/2015 02:52 PM",
"01/02/2015 02:55 PM")

cost <- c(8, 2, 50, 26, 7)

df <- data.frame(times = times, cost = cost, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


#### convert times to POSIX dates
df$times <- strptime(df$times, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")

### polling frequency in minutes
pollinglength <- 15

### create empty vector to hold sums
amount <- rep(NA, nrow(df))

for( i in 1:nrow(df)){

  ### POSIX support comparison operators well
  upperWindow <- df$times <= df$times[i]

  ### POSIX does not support addition/subtraction well, so we will convert to numeric first
  lowerWindow <- as.numeric(df$times) > (as.numeric(df$times[i]) - pollinglength * 60)

  amount[i] <- sum(df$cost[ upperWindow & lowerWindow ])
}

### Add back to data frame
df <- cbind(df, amount)
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for this! But what I want to do is sum the data from the second data frame (customer data) across the dates from the first data frame (stamp data), cost is really just an arbitrary column here, I included it to show that I want it to be in the final data frame.

Comment: No problem. Go ahead and mark it as an answer if it solves your problem. Otherwise let me know if you need help.

Comment: If the problem is that they are in separate data frames, run

Comment: cbind(stamp, customer) beforehand. If the data frames don't have the same number of rows, look into the merge function.

Comment: Yeah, the data frames don't have the same number of rows. So if I merge the sets first, can I then do the above?

Comment: Yes, if you can merge them in a way that makes sense, as in with a common column, then the above will work.

Comment: The issue with merging is that the datasets don't contain headers that I could really match on-- the whole point is that one contains supply-side data, and the other is demand-side, so I want to sum the Amount data from the demand-side, to understand how the supply-side data is driving performance for a given time window (in our case, 15 minutes after the supply-data timestamp)

Comment: We are going to need more info to answer this.

Comment: The supply side data (stamp data) shows when we decided to put a product out on the website, the demand side data (customer data) shows the time at which someone went to purchase an item from the website. I want to sum up the demand side data within a 15 minute window of when we decided to put a product out on the website.